# How old fashioned way of creating new MouseEvent looks?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createEvent and in older version they omit some details when presenting the older way.

I have certain code:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.mouseDownLeftButton = function () {
    var event = new MouseEvent('mousedown',
    {
        'which': 1,
        'view': window,
        'bubbles': true,
        'cancelable': true
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

which is not executed properly in some environments. Thus I wrote a version in old-fashioned way:

```
HTMLElement.prototype.mouseDownLeftButton = function () {
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    event.initEvent("mousedown", true, false);
    event.setAttribute("which", 1);//how to do it correctly?
    event.setAttribute("view", window);//how to do it correctly?
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

but unfortunately I get:

> TypeError: event.setAttribute is not a function

**Question:** How to properly set `which` to `1` and `view` to `window` in older fashion? To clarify `which: 1` says that the left mouse button have been "downed".

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `event.currentTarget.setAttribute` and use just `event.which` property, which will detect

```
1 - Left
2 - Middle
3 - Right
```

JS

```
HTMLElement.prototype.mouseDownLeftButton = function () {
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvent");
    event.initEvent("mousedown", true, false);
    event.setAttribute("which", event.which);//how to do it correctly?
    event.setAttribute("view", window);//how to do it correctly?
    this.dispatchEvent(event);
};
```

Comment: Thank you, but I get: `Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null`.

Comment: @Yoda have you attached your event to something ?

Comment: Yeah I did but `event.which` and `event.view` just helped. But I need to check on the other environments.